# In R, what does a negative index do?

Tags: r, syntax, indexing, matrix-indexing

I am porting part of a program (not enough to compile and run) from R to C++.  I am not familiar with R.  I have done okay using the references online, but was stumped by the following line:

```
cnt2.2<-cnt2[,-1]
```

I am guessing:

1. `cnt2` is a 2 dimensional matrix
2. `cnt2.2` is a new variable being declared with a period '.' used the same way an alphabetic character would be.
3. `<-` is an assignment.
4. `[,-1]` accesses part of the array.  I thought `[,5]` meant all rows, 5th column only.  If this is correct, I have no idea what -1 refers to.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is covered in section 2.7 of the manual: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Index-vectors

It is a negative index into the `cnt2` object specifying all rows and all columns except the first column.

Answer (score 20):

Negative indices specify dropping (rather than retaining) particular elements ... so `x[,-1]` specifies dropping the first column (rows are the first dimension, before the comma, and columns are the second dimension, after the comma).  From `?"["` ( http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html ):

> For ‘[’-indexing only: ‘i’, ‘j’, ‘...’ can be logical
>                 vectors, indicating elements/slices to select.  Such vectors
>                 are recycled if necessary to match the corresponding extent.
>                 ‘i’, ‘j’, ‘...’ can also be negative integers, indicating
>                 elements/slices to leave out of the selection.

Answer (score 9):

> 1) cnt2 is a 2 dimensional matrix

From the code you provided it is indeed a 2-dimensional structure of some sort (quite possibly a matrix).

> 2) cnt2.2 is a new variable being declared with a period '.' used the same way an alphabetic character would be.

Correct.

> 3) <- is an assignment.

Correct.

> 4) [,-1] accesses part of the array. I thought [,5] meant all rows, 5th column only. If this is correct, I have no idea what -1 refers to.

`[,-1]` selects all columns *except column 1*. Note that, unlike in C++, indices in R start from one rather than zero.

Comment: +1 for comment about indexing from 1 (although I hope the OP has already figured this out)