# what does data[ , -i] mean in R

Tags: r, matrix

In many functions I see things like data[, -i], if it is data[ , i] it mean refers to a particular column and all rows.Does that mean we are ommiting that column? data is a table that holds a csv file in my case.

Comment: What makes you think it will ommit column `i`. Have you tried? Have you found some documentation?

Comment: im new to R. In one fuction it seemed to omit the particular column in the iteration.but in another it dint seem to. In most cases i felt it omited the column.

Comment: From the help of the `[` function (run ?'[' in your `R` session): "For ‘[’-indexing only: ‘i’, ‘j’, ‘...’ can be logical
          vectors, indicating elements/slices to select.  Such vectors
          are recycled if necessary to match the corresponding extent.
          ‘i’, ‘j’, ‘...’ can also be negative integers, indicating
          elements/slices to leave out of the selection.
"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336679/in-r-what-does-cnt2-2-cnt2-1-do/7336746#7336746

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a - in [] does exactly that! Look at the example below and try other kinda examples yourself.

```
> a<-1:10
> a[-1]
[1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
> a[-(1:3)]
[1]  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Works similarly with matrices:

```
> a<-matrix(1:4,2,2)
> a
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4
> a[,-1]
[1] 3 4
```

Have a great day!