# Remove all rows which do not contain a specific string in R

Tags: r

I'm still learning many things about how to use R, however I'm facing an issue which I haven't been able to find any answers for yet.

In my dataframe ("data"), the rows are for each participant and for each participants' trials on a given task. The columns contain different information about these participants. It looks a little bit like this:

```
Participant    Age     Sex    Trial.Type       correct
     P01       26       0       test              1
     P01       26       0       test              0
     P01       26       0       control           1
     P02       32       1       test              1
     P02       32       1       control           1
     P02       32       1       demographics      NA
```

I would like to create a new dataframe df. In this dataframe, I would like to remove all the rows that do NOT contain the string "test" in the data$Trial.Type column.

I have seen that in order to remove all the rows that contain a specific string, I could use the following function:

```
df <- data[-grep("test", data$Trial.Type),]
```

Which works great to remove all rows that contain the "test" string, but actually I would like to do the opposite, and remove all the rows except those with the "test" string (and in a more efficient way than running the function above for each non "test" strings).

I hope I was clear enough and I followed the rules, it's my first post on StackOverflow

Comment: try using `df <- data[!grepl("test", data$Trial.Type), ]`.

Comment: In case we want exact match, just use: `dataSubset <- data[ data$Trial.Type == "test", ]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
df <- data[grep("test", data$Trial.Type),]
```

---

### Explanation

`grep` returns the indices of every match of the pattern, in your case `"test"`. When you use the negatived indices you effectively exclude the matches (see [In R, what does a negative index do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336679/in-r-what-does-a-negative-index-do)), and using them as they come (*i.e.* positive indices) is the same as only returning the matches, excluding everything else.